# Image inside Picture box not maintaining its scale/aspect ratio

Tags: c#, forms, graphics, aspect-ratio

I currently have an image (1280px,1024px) on a main form and the user is able to click an option to draw a box round the image. When they click this option, a new form opens up with the image inside a picture box of size 526,302  and fills the picture box (ive used Zoom but the this makes the image not fill the box and using Stretch does this but does not maintain the aspect ratio.

What i am wanting is, when the user starts making the square box, where they click will maintain the 1280,1024px ratio, at the moment, if i click on the bottom right of the image, the mouse.x and mouse.y comes up at around 400,500 not the expected values of around 1200, 1000.

Can anyone see why this might be?

Here is the code i have.

```
namespace Valo.CustomDraw
{

/// <summary>
/// Class which controls what happens when the user selected to create a custom view to focus on 
/// with the camera. It creates a form which the user draws a rectabnge on. It's height, width and 
/// starting mouse point are calcualted and sent the main window class to be processed appropriately. 
/// </summary>
public partial class bitmap_Square : Form
{

    #region instance variabls

    public Point p1;                    //starting point of rectangle.
    public Point p2;                    //ending point of rectangle.
    MainForm mainApp;                   //reference to the MainForm which called this form.
    Bitmap bmp;                         //bitmap of the camera imag (1280px, 1024px)
    int [] rectDim = new int [2];       //dimentions of the rectangle (width, height).
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Constuctor that starts the application. 
    /// It creates the form with bitmap image in and applies the mouse listeners
    /// and pain functionality to the picture box as well as controlling the response
    /// from the 'apply button'.
    /// </summary>
    public bitmap_Square(Bitmap b, MainForm ma)
    {
        //initialses the form object.
        InitializeComponent();

        //assigns the passed in MainForm paramater to the local instance.
        mainApp = ma;
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        //assigns the passed in bitmap from the MainForm to a local instance.
        this.bmp = b;

        MessageBox.Show("" + bmp.Width);
        MessageBox.Show("" + bmp.Height);

        //pb_bitmapImage.Image = scaledBMP;
        pb_bitmapImage.Image = bmp;
        pb_bitmapImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        //invalidates the picture box so it can be drawn on.
        pb_bitmapImage.Invalidate();
        MessageBox.Show("" + bmp.Width);
        MessageBox.Show("" + bmp.Height);

        //adding the MouseEventHandler and PaintEventHandler.
        pb_bitmapImage.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Bitmap_Square_Paint);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Bitmap_Square_MouseDown);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Bitmap_Square_MouseMove);
        pb_bitmapImage.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Bitmap_Square_MouseUp);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse_Down event handler which deals with what happens when the mouse is pressed down
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Bitmap_Square_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            p1 = e.Location;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse_Down event handler which deals with what happens when the mouse is moved
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Bitmap_Square_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p2 = e.Location;
            pb_bitmapImage.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse_Down event handler which deals with what happens when the mouse is released
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Bitmap_Square_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p2 = e.Location;
            pb_bitmapImage.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manages the paint method when the mouse is moved and ensures the lines are drawn
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Bitmap_Square_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        //calcuates what lines to draw when tou move your mouse accross the screen and 
        //draws them onto the bitmap inside the picture box.
        if (p1.X > 0 && p1.Y > 0 && p2.X > 0 && p2.Y > 0)
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When pressed, it then calls the method from the MainForm which sets the Custom View and changes
    /// labels etc in on the main form to refect this as well as the calculation to focus the camera.
    /// It works out the width and heigh before calling this method as these values are part of the 
    /// parameter list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btn_rectApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Rectangle Height
        rectDim[0] = (p2.X - p1.X);
        //Rectangle Width
        rectDim[1] = (p2.Y - p1.Y);

        MessageBox.Show("" + p1.X);
        MessageBox.Show("" + p1.Y);
        MessageBox.Show("" + p2.X);
        MessageBox.Show("" + p2.Y);
        MessageBox.Show("" + rectDim[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("" + rectDim[1]);


        //method call from the MainForm to initiate the changes to the Form to reflect the newly 
        //selected area.);
        mainApp.ApplyScreenSelection("Current View: Custom", p1.X, p1.Y, rectDim[0], rectDim[1]);
        this.Close();


    }

}
```

[image: Main Window for user]

[image: Screen user gets when drawing image. I need the aspect ratio to stay the same]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark but I think you might need to calculate the x and y coordinate where you make the selection as a percentage and then apply the percentage to the actual image dimentions. So if your selection area is 526 x 302 and you select x = 450 and y = 250, those coordinates in percentages in relation to the selection area are x = 450 / 526 * 100 = 85.55 and y = 250 / 302 * 100 = 82.78. Now that we have x and y as percentages we can calculate the selection point in relation to the full size image, so x = 85.55 / 100 * 1280 = 1095.04 and y = 82.78 / 100 * 1024 = 847.67 hope this helps :)

Comment: Cheers Michael, even when we're not at uni, you're still a great help :D I'll try this today :)